# How to use modules in ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, commonjs

I try use this code for example, and compile this code with Babel

```
let notExported = 'abc';
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export const MY_CONSTANT = 123;
```

after compile:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
exports.square = square;
var notExported = 'abc';
function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
var MY_CONSTANT = exports.MY_CONSTANT = 123;
```

but browser show error: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**".  What i do wrong? Maybe i need use some libs (if yes, how do it)?

Comment: Are you using require.js to load your modules?

Comment: i dont use on browser side any modules

Comment: on server side i use Gulp

Comment: yes. maybe i should use some plugins on browser side?

Answer (score 2):

Babel will convert ES6 module syntax into other module formats. The default one is CommonJS. Node supports CommonJS by default. If you wish to use CommonJS modules in a browser, you'll need to use Babel along side a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify. You'd use something along the lines of:

```
npm install browserify babelify
```

and bundle with

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify -t babelify yourFile.js -o bundledFile.js
```

then load `bundledFile.js` in your browser.